# Counter Strike 1.6 not working on mac

Tags: macos, counter-strike

[image: This is a screenshot of the error message i am receiving on opening the app.]

I am using it for the very first time. I have no idea about the error I am receiving.

I am using wineskin.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to using an old version of Wineskin in the wrapper, one which does not play nicely with the System Integrity Protection (or "rootless") functionality in Yosemite (OS X 10.11). There are two ways to deal with this:

**1. Update Wineskin (and your wrappers) to 2.6.1**

[Wineskin 2.6.1](http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com/tiki-view_blog_post.php?postId=82) fixes the issue with rootless mode and really you should just take the time to keep Wineskin up to date anyway. Assuming you have Wineskin Winery installed, you should be able to update your wrappers from there.

**2. [Disable rootless](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11) (not recommended)**

Disabling security functionality is generally a bad idea, but it is an alternate way to deal with the problem. If you must, follow these steps (quoted from the linked answer):

> 1. Reboot your Mac into Recovery Mode by restarting your computer and holding down <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> until the Apple logo appears on your screen.
> 2. Click Utilities > Terminal.
> 3. In the Terminal window, type in `csrutil disable` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
> 4. Restart your Mac.

Comment: I have updated wineskin now. But now when I open the game, I do not get any error message but the screen goes blank and and then I am back on my desktop.

Comment: Have you reinstalled the Wineskin engine in that wrapper? It may help, according to the 2.6.1 patch notes. (If it does, LMK and I will add that step to the post.)

Comment: I tried doing that too....but it did not work...guess there is something wrong with my copy of the game...but still thanks a lot... :)